OAuth 2.0 Auth URL returns error 500 for the person in charge
Using my Xero trial account with accepted invitation into our company Xero account I created Xero OAuth 2.0 app. Then I need the authorization code to be able to get tokens and have access to Xero API. I sent the Auth URL to my colleague who has permissions to grant me access to our company data so she can pass me the authorization code but the Auth URL isn’t working for her. Everything is set up correctly according to Xero YouTube videos and documentation. The URL works because when I access it, it prompts me to log in and gives me selection for an organization. But I don’t have permission to select our organization which is greyed out. My colleague is supposed to grant access to me but the link is not working for her. Please give me hint what are most common reasons for this issue. Any help is highly appreciated as we need to hurry with our internal reporting and we have lack of data when we can’t access them.
We tried different browsers, I tried to adjust scopes, my colleague invited me into our organization but nothing worked to resolve the issue.

500 error almost always means a server-side bug. If I got a 500 error interacting with a third party API i would contact their support.

For most error 500 issues there is a small sentence under the error indicating what the problem is eg 'invalid redirect uri'.
Without having access to further details it is hard to troubleshoot, please can you raise a case with Xero Support here and include the client id, a screen shot of the error, the date and time of the most recent error (and your timezone) and the name of the organisation
